# How to recover bitcoin from Coinbase?

Tags: wallet, address, coinbase-transaction

My Bitcoin wallet has generated 1st key and, later, the 2nd one. I have used the first address for a transaction from my coinbase exchange to my coinbase wallet, but the funds did not arrive, perhaps because the 2nd address has already been generated. How can I receive my funds, which used the 1st address? Thnak you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Addresses never expire. Even if you generate hundreds or thousands of new addresses, money sent to an old address in future years will still be under your control, assuming you make backups of your private keys using your wallet's backup feature and don't keep everything on one device.

Normally, wallets play no part in receiving money but will fetch blockchain data to calculate your current balance. Your wallet is your window onto the blockchain.

You can get the transaction-ID from the exchange and check the status of that transaction-ID at any [blockchain explorer](https://www.google.com/search?q=blockchain+explore).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you might have mixed the private key and the receiving address?
The wallet app generates receiving addresses based off of the private key.

If you used a receiving address from the 1st private key, sent bitcoin to it, and then switched the app to another private key, you might just not see the transfer on your receiving address in the app.

If this is the case, you need to switch the app back to the 1st private key.

If you are using Electrum, it stores the private key info into a file, I'm hoping you have not deleted this file.